# Pandas Dataframe and If Conditions

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

I have a dataframe. But in this dataframe, I just want to use just a column.
İts name is data_state2['Quantity Total First']

For math operation others df are data_state2['Rate2'] = data_state['Rate1']

I want to construct an if statement. In other words, if it is within a certain number range, let it do the mathematical calculation I want. But when I try to do it I can't use if with dataframe.

Can you help me?

```
if data_state2[(data_state2['Quantity Total First'] <= 500000000)]:
  data_state2['Rate1'] = data_state['Rate']
elif data_state2[(data_state2["Quantity Total First"] >= 50000000) & (data_state2["Quantity Total First"] <= 500000000)]:
  data_state2['Rate1'] = data_state['Rate']*0.9 + data_state2['Rate1']*0.1
elif data_state2[(data_state2["Quantity Total First"] >= 500000000) & (data_state2["Quantity Total First"] <= 2000000000)]:
    data_state2['Rate1'] = data_state['Rate']*0.8 + data_state2['Rate1']*0.2
elif data_state2[(data_state2["Quantity Total First"] >= 2000000000) & (data_state2["Quantity Total First"] <= 4000000000)]:
    data_state2['Rate1'] = data_state['Rate']*0.5 + data_state2['Rate1']*0.5
elif data_state2[(data_state2["Quantity Total First"] >= 4000000000) & (data_state2["Quantity Total First"] <= 6000000000)]:
    data_state2['Rate1'] = data_state['Rate']*0.25 + data_state2['Rate1']*0.75
else:
    data_state2['Rate1']


ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: Please provide some sample data (i.e. provide an [mre]).

Comment: Can you check my example?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72734425/numpy-where-missing-length-of-values-via-python

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.where`

```py
data_state2['Rate1'] = np.where(
    [data_state2['Quantity Total First'] <= 500000000,
     (data_state2["Quantity Total First"] >= 50000000) & (data_state2["Quantity Total First"] <= 500000000),
     (data_state2["Quantity Total First"] >= 500000000) & (data_state2["Quantity Total First"] <= 2000000000),
     (data_state2["Quantity Total First"] >= 2000000000) & (data_state2["Quantity Total First"] <= 4000000000),
     (data_state2["Quantity Total First"] >= 4000000000) & (data_state2["Quantity Total First"] <= 6000000000),
     ],
    [data_state['Rate'],
     data_state['Rate']*0.9 + data_state2['Rate1']*0.1,
     data_state['Rate']*0.8 + data_state2['Rate1']*0.2,
     data_state['Rate']*0.5 + data_state2['Rate1']*0.5,
     data_state['Rate']*0.25 + data_state2['Rate1']*0.75
     ],
    data_state2['Rate1']
)
```

Comment: TypeError: where() got an unexpected keyword argument 'default' . Can you check it?

Comment: ValueError: Length of values (5) does not match length of index (1728)

Comment: my real dataframe len is 1728. Maybe it occurs for it

Comment: @Bianconera99 The length of your `data_state` and `data_state2` doesn't match.

Comment: how can I fix it?

Comment: @Bianconera99 No idea.

Comment: can you create new dataframe for me as squally?

Comment: I think its not about datastate and datastate2. You wrote lenght of values (5) but data state2 has 1728 index.

Comment: @Bianconera99 I guess `data_state` only has 5 rows.