# Numpy Where missing length of values via Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

My code is raising error like "
ValueError: Length of values (5) does not match length of index (1728)"

my datastate2 df has 1728 index. How can I improve this code? Can you help me?

My data_state might be 5 rows, but How can I arrange them ?

There is a total amount that I want and calculate. This total amount is kept in the Quantity Total First section in the data_state2 section. If this is in a certain range, Rate in data_state and rate1 in data_State2 will be calculated with a certain weighting rate. Here if situations come into play, because Quantity Total First can be in any range, weighting ratios will be used accordingly.

```
data_state2['Rate1'] = np.where(
    [data_state2['Quantity Total First'] <= 500000000,
     (data_state2["Quantity Total First"] >= 50000000) & (data_state2["Quantity Total First"] <= 500000000),
     (data_state2["Quantity Total First"] >= 500000000) & (data_state2["Quantity Total First"] <= 2000000000),
     (data_state2["Quantity Total First"] >= 2000000000) & (data_state2["Quantity Total First"] <= 4000000000),
     (data_state2["Quantity Total First"] >= 4000000000) & (data_state2["Quantity Total First"] <= 6000000000),
     ],
    [data_state['Rate'],
     data_state['Rate']*0.9 + data_state2['Rate1']*0.1,
     data_state['Rate']*0.8 + data_state2['Rate1']*0.2,
     data_state['Rate']*0.5 + data_state2['Rate1']*0.5,
     data_state['Rate']*0.25 + data_state2['Rate1']*0.75
     ],
    data_state2['Rate1']
```

My input (1);

data_state2 >>my dataframe is 1728 rows. The most important column that I will use in the calculation is Quantity Total Price. I mean data_state2['Quantity Total Price']. this column has the number 200,000,000 and 1728 have the same raw.

| Quantity Total Price |
| --- |
| 200000000 |
| 200000000 |
| 200000000 |
| 200000000 |
| 200000000 |
| n.. |

My input (2); data_state2 >> Same as the dataframe in item 1 above, but another column. I mean data_state2['Rate1']. this column has the number 14.5 and 1728 have the same raw.

| Rate1 |
| --- |
| 14.5 |
| 14.5 |
| 14.5 |
| 14.5 |
| 14.5 |
| n.. |

My input (3);
data_state >> It is a dataframe that is different from the dataframe in the above and has 1728 rows. I mean data_state['Rate']. this column has the number 15 and 1728 have the same raw.

| Rate |
| --- |
| 15 |
| 15 |
| 15 |
| 15 |
| 15 |
| 15 |

My expected output;

```
if datastate2['Quantity Price First'] <= 500000000 then, I want to use data_state['Rate'] directly instead of data_state2['Rate1'] by creating a new column.

For example, Quantity Total First: 200000000  and according my if statement 200000000<=500000000 then, create new column and write 15 I mean data_state['Rate']

other cases are listed below.

 data_state2["Quantity Total First"] >= 50000000) & (data_state2["Quantity Total First"] <= 500000000) then,
calculate >> data_state['Rate']*0.9 + data_state2['Rate1']*0.1
 
for example;
Suppose that quantity total: 1500000000 that is, it is within the two ranges I have determined.
calculate >> (15 * 0.9) + (14.5 * 0.1) = 14.95

(data_state2["Quantity Total First"] >= 2000000000) & (data_state2["Quantity Total First"] <= 4000000000)
calculate >> data_state['Rate']*0.5 + data_state2['Rate1']*0.5

(data_state2["Quantity Total First"] >= 2000000000) & (data_state2["Quantity Total First"] <= 4000000000)
calculate >> data_state['Rate']*0.25 + data_state2['Rate1']*0.75


else: (data_state2["Quantity Total First"] >= 4000000000) & (data_state2["Quantity Total First"] <= 6000000000)

use directly >> data_state['Rate1'] I mean 14.5
```

Comment: So what's the question?  Why the `where` gives an array or Series with only 5 values, or why you can't assign that to a Series/column with 1700 values?

Comment: Updated. Thnx for help